# Zend: Form Validation After AJAX

Tags: zend-framework

I have a form done with Zend. I load it with ajax in a dialog. It has 2 selects. Depending on what is selected in the first select, it loads the content of the second one. However, when I submit the form I get a validation error because the options of the second form weren't there at the time of creating it.

Is there a way to fix this "issue"? It does what it needs to do but I don't want it to verify that field anymore. Any way to specify that I don't want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the `inArray` validator. When constructing the form's `select` element, set

```
'registerInArrayValidator' => false
```

Also, a different solution would be to overload the `isValid` method, inspect the selected option for the first `select` element and then populate the options for the second element. Then call `parent::isValid` to check if the form is in fact valid or not.